# Spring Boot Docker com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: docker, spring-boot

this is my Eureka Server **application.property**

```
# set port
server.port=8761
# no need to register the server with the server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
# don't need a local copy of the registry
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Eureka Server *dockerfile*

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/eureka-service.jar eureka-service.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "eureka-service.jar"]
```

Eureka Client *application.property*

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Eureka Client *dockerfile*

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/foo.jar foo.jar
EXPOSE 8971
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "foo.jar"]
```

Eureka server is annotated with *@EnableEurekaServer* and Eureka client is annotate with *@EnableEurekaClient*

The client is successfully registered with EurekaServer and everything is working fine. But when i try to run this in Docker using below

## Docker-Compose.yml

version: "2.0"

```
services:
 foo-service:
  build: foo/
  ports: 
  - "8761:8761"

 bar-service:
  build: bar/
  ports: 
  - "8971:8971"
```

The client is unable to register with server. and getting below stacktrace.

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
      |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I am really a new guy in Docker , Any help ?

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997711/eurekaserver-com-netflix-discovery-shared-transport-transportexception-cannot-e/63006904#63006904

Answer (score 1):

Modify `dockerfile` of `EurekaServer` to:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/eureka-service.jar eureka-service.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT java -jar Eureka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar eureka
```

Modify `dockerfile` of `EurekaClient` to:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/foo.jar foo.jar
EXPOSE 8971
ENTRYPOINT java -jar foo.jar foo
```

In the property file for `EurekaClient`, modify this property

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:8761/eureka
```

Now separately build the image for both the apps.
In the `docker-compose.yml`, there you will need to add some configurations to link the client with the server. The modified docker-compose will look something like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  eureka:
    image: eureka:latest
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"
    networks:
    - webnet
  noob:
    image: foo:latest
    ports:
    - "8971:8971"
    networks:
    - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

Cheers!